# Does using ipv6 speed up file transfers?

Tags: ipv6, windows-server-2012

I did some googling but I can't find everything on this topic. I always disable `IPv6` on my home server because I ran into Active Directory problems.

I was wondering if using `IPv6` speed up file transfers?

Comment: Note that the IP layer just handles addressing and internetwork transport. any mutations to data that might result in it being faster to transport over the exact same media (like compression) would be handled at a higher layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference between `IPv4` or `IPv6` protocols (more precise: protocol *stacks*) are mainly about *addressing hosts*, but other protocols may be (and are) also affected.

For example, every `IP` packet contains source and destination addresses, which are only `32-bits` long for `IPv4` but `128-bits` for `IPv6`.

So `IPv6` may be little slower for file transfers, not faster.

But there are other factors (e. g. translating from `IPv6` to `IPv4` and vice versa in the way on routers truly supporting only one of these) which may have impact on the speed.

Comment: While there are transition techniques (6rd, NAT64 and whatnot), they aren’t widely employed. A regular router doesn’t deal with those anyway.

Comment: They are more widely deployed than you think. Mobile carriers  are by far the largest users but also office networks are migrating to NAT64 these days. For example Microsoft itself is moving in that direction for their own offices: https://blog.apnic.net/2017/01/19/ipv6-only-at-microsoft/